# An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE... ': Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

**DefaultFormHandler.php**

```
  protected function onSuccess($object)
    {        
            $artistmember= new ArtistMember();
            $artistmember->setMemberId($object->getManager()->getId());
            $artistmember->setArtistId($object->getId());
            $this->em->merge($artistmember);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $object;
     }
```

**ArtistMember**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="artist_member")
 */
class ArtistMember
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="artist_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $artist_id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="member_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $member_id;


    /**
     * @param mixed $artist_id
     */
    public function setArtistId($artist_id)
    {
        $this->artist_id = $artist_id;
    }
    /**
     * @param mixed $member_id
     */
    public function setMemberId($member_id)
    {
        $this->member_id = $member_id;
    }



}
```

**entity artist get manager()**

```
/**
     * Set manager
     *
     * @param Member $manager
     */
    public function setManager($manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;

        if ( ! $this->members->contains( $manager) ) {
            $this->members->add( $manager );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get manager
     *
     * @return \MainBundle\Entity\Member
     */
    public function getManager()
    {
        return $this->manager;
    }
```

I have 2 tables: `Artist` table  and `member` table

In `artist table` I have the `id` and `manager_id` and in `member` table I have `member_id` and `artist_id`.

Update query works fine if the `member` table contains only `one artist_id` and `member_id`.
Eg: artist-id=1,manager_id =10.
But I get the above error if I try to update any of the manager id in this case:

```
eg: artist_id=1
    member_id=10
    artist_id=1
    member_id =20
```

If I try to update the `member id` `20` to `30` or `10` to `30` I am getting the error.
The issue is resolved with this solution: But still is there a better way to do it?Also is it possible to check whether the artist_id and member_id are already existing in artist_member table.

Comment: The solution works if I do this:protected function onSuccess($object)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE artist_member SET member_id=".$object->getManager()->getId()."  WHERE member_id=(select manager_id from artist where id=".$object->getId().") and artist_id=".$object->getId();
        $stmt = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $this->em->persist($object);
        $this->em->flush();
        return $object;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory:

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE… ': Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

The issue is when you try to update the manager id `20 to 30` or `10 to 30`, the new value you are trying to update are already present in the column.